# Python matplotlib bars grouped by week

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following python sample.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x= ['Ja', 'Nein', 'Ja', 'Nein', 'Ja', 'Nein'] 
y = [60, 46, 31, 37, 1, 3]
week = [27.0, 27.0, 28.0, 28.0, 29.0, 29.0]

x_pos = [i for i, _ in enumerate(x)]

plt.bar(x_pos, y, color='green')

plt.xticks(x_pos, x)

plt.show()
```

I would like to order the bars by week, meaning blue bars for week 27, red bars for 28
, green bars for 29 always shown for the x values. The y is the count for that combination.

Can anyone help?

Best
Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a color mapping between weeks and the color you want for that week and pass a list of colors when creating your figure:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x= ['Ja', 'Nein', 'Ja', 'Nein', 'Ja', 'Nein'] 
y = [60, 46, 31, 37, 1, 3]
week = [27.0, 27.0, 28.0, 28.0, 29.0, 29.0]

x_pos = [i for i, _ in enumerate(x)]

# Mapping from week to color:
week_to_color = {
    27.0: 'blue',
    28.0: 'red',
    29.0: 'green',
}

# Pass a list of colors to your bar chart:
plt.bar(x_pos, y, color=[week_to_color[w] for w in week])

plt.xticks(x_pos, x)

plt.show()
```

[image: Bar chart]